# Using a barrier causes a CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE error

Tags: opencl, reduction, jocl

If I use a barrier (no matter if `CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE` or `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE`) in my kernel, it causes a `CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` error. The global work size is 512, the local work size is 128, 65536 items have to be computed, the max work group size of my device is 1024, I am using only one dimension. For Java bindings I use JOCL. 
The kernel is very simple:

```
kernel void sum(global float *input, global float *output, const int numElements, local float *localCopy
{
    localCopy[get_local_id(0)] = grid[get_global_id(0)];
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); // or barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)
}
```

I run the kernel on the `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5570 @ 2.93GHz` and can use OpenCL 1.2. The calling method looks like

```
kernel.putArg(aCLBuffer).putArg(bCLBuffer).putArg(elementCount).putNullArg(localWorkSize);
queue.put1DRangeKernel(kernel, 0, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize);
```

But the error is always the same:

```
[...]can not enqueue 1DRange CLKernel [...] with gwo: null gws: {512} lws: {128} 
cond.: null events: null [error: CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the JOCL bindings, but the call: putNullArg(localWorkSize) seems to be allocating bytes of local memory. I think you need to try: putNullArg(localWorkSize * 4), or the java equivalent of putNullArg(localWorkSize * sizeof(float))

Comment: unless  localWorkSize is already multiplied..

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. The JOCL documentation says nothing about byte size ( http://goo.gl/ALkBLw ), just `size`, so I assume (and trying says also), that it is not the problem.

Comment: does the error happen for other group sizes? 1, 16, 32 etc?

Comment: No, for local work size = 1 it does work, but not for > 1.

Comment: I run the kernel on the `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5570 @ 2.93GHz`and can use OpenCL 1.2

Comment: Out of interest, is this an Apple system? I've never seen this on Intel/AMD platforms, so just want to make sure that is still the case.

Comment: Yes, it is an Apple system, but with Intel Xeon processors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behaviour on some OpenCL platforms. For example, on my Apple system, the CPU device has a maximum work-group size of 1024. However, if a kernel has a barrier inside, then the maximum work-group size for that specific kernel is reduced to 1.

You can query the maximum work-group size for a specific kernel by using the `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo` function with the `CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` parameter. The value returned will be no more than the value returned by `clGetDeviceInfo` and `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`, but is allowed to be less (as it is in this case).

Comment: Are you sure this is "expected behaviour"? Do you have a standard quote? Unless I'm missing something, such behaviour would render `barrier` completely useless.

Comment: @Cicada The OpenCL specification allows specific kernels to have maximum work-group sizes that are smaller than the device's maximum. This happens frequently for other reasons too - if your kernel uses lots of registers on a GPU, the maximum work-group size can be reduced. By 'expected behaviour', I mean that the behaviour is allowed, and some platforms are known to do this. I agree that this is a pain for developers, since it does mean that you can't do any useful synchronisation.

Comment: @jprice Oh, I see. That's a bummer indeed. +1

Comment: So, if you need synchronization, you can't launch a work group of more than 1 work item, but synchronizing a single work item is functionally equivalent to having no synchronization at all. In other words, that device doesn't support synchronization, is that right?

Comment: @Cicada Yes, it basically implies that the implementors couldn't be bothered to implement any synchronisation for that particular platform. This might mean that each work-item is mapped onto a different thread, which would make synchronisation expensive. Other CPU implementations map a work-*group* onto a thread and then serialise work-item execution within that thread, which makes synchronisation much easier and cheaper.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks :) I always thought the Intel implementation mapped work items to SSE SIMD lanes.

Comment: @Cicada Yes Intel's implementation does indeed do that, with the entire work-group executing within a single thread. I suspect the OP is using Apple's OpenCL implementation, which isn't so intelligent.

Comment: @jprice I experimented myself on multiple platforms and I knew that kernel WG size is sometimes smaller (registers, etc). But I never encountered a case were it would be 1. I think this is only applicable to CPU OpenCL emulations. However for a good practice, the developer should always read the value provided by the API, and calculate the best size taking that into account. Its a good way of having multiplatform fitted adjust of the kernels.